# how to stop function in js?

Tags: javascript, function

I have a form that counts when a button (`button.clicked` in the example below) is clicked. I want to make it operate in two modes: one keeps counting with every click, the other has a timer (started with the click of another button, `button.start`) that will disable the click-count button when the timer runs out. Each mode is chosen by clicking a button (`button.menu-timer` and `button.menu-clicks`). When the count mode is selected, one function (`cc`) is called. When switched to the timer mode, another function (`tt`) should be called and the first function should stop.

If I click one mode button, then everything works as it should, but if after that I click the other mode button, both functions continue to operate; each click of `button.click` adds two to the count. Moreover, if you click the mode buttons several times, clicking the count button will increase the counter many times, rather than only once.

I searched for solutions on the Internet and found one based on `return`; I tried to use `return` in various ways but couldn't get it to work.

I need that when choosing the right mode, only the desired function works. And so that when you click several times on one mode, the function will run once.

The following snippet is also available on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/createchaoslab/pen/GRGjRar).

```js
let clicker = document.querySelector(".click");
let start = document.querySelector(".start");
let clickerValue = document.querySelector(".click").value;
const reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
const menuTimer = document.querySelector(".menu-timer");
const menuClicks = document.querySelector(".menu-clicks");
const times = document.querySelectorAll(".time");
let i = 0;
let y;
let tf;
let timer = 15;
function tt(tf) {
  if (tf ===2) {
    return;
  }
  start.addEventListener("click", () => {
    start.style.zIndex = "-1";
    y = setInterval(() => {
      if (i === timer) {
        clicker.setAttribute("disabled", "");
      } else {
        i++;
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
  clicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clicker.textContent = clickerValue++;
  });
  reset.addEventListener("click", resetF);
}

function cc(tf) {
   if (tf = 1) {
    return;
  }
  start.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("111111");
    start.style.zIndex = "-1";
  });
  clicker.addEventListener("click", () => {
    clicker.textContent = `a ${clickerValue++}`;
  });
  reset.addEventListener("click", resetF);

}
function resetF() {
  clearInterval(y);
  i = 0;
  start.style.zIndex = "2";
  clickerValue = 0;
  clicker.textContent = clickerValue;
  clicker.removeAttribute("disabled", "");
}
menuTimer.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menuTimer.classList.add("active");
  menuClicks.classList.remove("active");
  tt(1);
  resetF();
});

menuClicks.addEventListener("click", function () {
  menuClicks.classList.add("active");
  menuTimer.classList.remove("active");
  cc(2)
  resetF();
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
    <button type="button" onclick="tf = 1" class="menu-timer">TIMER</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="tf = 2" class="menu-clicks">CLICKS</button>
</div>
<div class="click-btn">
    <button class="click" type="button">0</button>
    <button class="start" type="button">START</button>
</div>
<button class="reset" type="button">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[click() firing multiple times](/q/3460562/90527)", "[Click event listener fires multiple times](/q/63288658/90527)", "[Event handler being triggered multiple times](/q/65253355/90527)", "[Javascript conditional click event running multiple times](/q/47275159/90527)"

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo with assigning `=` instead of equality operator `===`

```
function cc(tf) {
       if (tf = 1) { // should be ===
        return;
      }
  ...
}
```

Also before you `addEventListener('click', ...)`, a good practice is to remove previous `click` listeners with `removeEventListener('click')`